# Chrome Dev Tools Command Line API selector $

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, when jQuery is loaded, the Dev Tools selector $ will be overridden. But is there a way that make this not happen in Dev Tools command line?

Answer (score 0):

Call `delete window.$;` and the default `$` will be back.

If that will break your website you can use `$$('selector')[0]` instead. It will return exactly the same thing as `$('selector')`.